# ¿Como obtengo las medidas correctas de una imagen mediante javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Mi problema es que quiero determinar de que tamaño como mínimo y como máximo deben de ser las imágenes que van a ingresar dentro de mi sistema web, tanto de longitud como de altura (width y height).

Aqui esta mi input de tipo archivo

```js
var img = document.getElementById('file-1');
var width = img.offsetWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
alert(width);
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file-1[]" id="file-1" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
```

Como se pueden dar cuenta tengo una alerta que da como resultado lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript) publicada en Stack Overflow *en inglés* puedes ver este código:

```js
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#file").change(function(e) {
  var file, img;
  if ((file = this.files[0])) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
    };
    img.onerror = function() {
      alert("not a valid file: " + file.type);
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

Este es el [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4N6D9/1/) para que lo veas funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder obtener las dimensiones de la imagen usando javascript, es necesario interpretar el archivo como una imagen, para ello creamos una nueva instancia de Image y agregamos el event onload para saber cuando la imagen este lista. Puede usar un callback para obtener los resultados como se muestra en el siguiente snippet :

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

function checkPhoto(target,callback) {
    var file, img;

    file = target.files[0];

    if (file) {
        img = new Image();

        img.onload = function () {
            callback(this.height, this.width, file.size);
        };

        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    } 
}

document.getElementById("photoInput").addEventListener("change",function(){
    checkPhoto(this,function(height,width,filesize){
        console.log(height,width,filesize);
        // Validar, si aplica
    });
},false);
```

Puede ver el [fiddle funcionando aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/m7Lc4L31/).