# Validar ancho imagen inputfile file-input bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-file-input

Estimados tengo el siguiente problema, estoy usando el plugin `File-Input` para cargar archivos a mi sistema. En este caso lo estoy usando para cargar imagenes las cuales proceso posteriomente mediante PHP. Mi duda es como puedo restringir un ancho minimo de imagenes a cargar. Para mi sistema mi resolucion ideal es de `1200x675`, quiero que el input no me permita cargar imagenes con un ancho menor al ideal, pero no logro dar con el resultado usando dicho plugin.

```js
$("#imagenes").fileinput({
  language: 'es',
  previewFileType: "image",
  browseClass: "btn btn-success",
  browseLabel: "Elegir Imagen",
  browseIcon: "<i class=\"icon-image\"></i> ",
  removeClass: "btn btn-danger",
  removeLabel: "Eliminar",
  removeIcon: "<i class=\"icon-cross\"></i> ",
  showUpload: false,
  dropZoneTitle: 'Arrastre aquí las imagenes a subir',
  maxFileSize: 200,
  maxFileCount: 5,
  showDelete: true,
  showRemove: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.1.2/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.1.2/css/fileinput.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-lg-6 col-12 mb-lg-0 mb-3 imagen-mascota">
  <input type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg" name="imagenes[]" id="imagenes" multiple>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como obtengo las medidas correctas de una imagen mediante javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20868/como-obtengo-las-medidas-correctas-de-una-imagen-mediante-javascript)

Comment: Lei lo que se sale en ese enlace, pero lo que yo quiero, es que si una imagen no cumple con el ancho minimo, este archivo no se pase al input file.

Answer (score 0):

Supuestamente según su [documentación](https://plugins.krajee.com/file-image-dimensions-demo#max-image-dimensions) se logra agregando las opciones:

```
maxImageWidth: 250,
maxImageHeight: 250
```

Pero al probarlo en firefox no me funcionó, por lo que [ya levaté el issue](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/issues/1649), en cuanto lo corrijan ya debería de funcionar.

```js
$("#imagenes").fileinput({
  language: 'es',
  previewFileType: "image",
  browseClass: "btn btn-success",
  browseLabel: "Elegir Imagen",
  browseIcon: "<i class=\"icon-image\"></i> ",
  removeClass: "btn btn-danger",
  removeLabel: "Eliminar",
  removeIcon: "<i class=\"icon-cross\"></i> ",
  showUpload: false,
  dropZoneTitle: 'Arrastre aquí las imagenes a subir',
  showPreview: true,
  maxFileCount: 5,
  //  maxFileSize: 200,
  showDelete: true,
  showRemove: true,
  maxImageWidth: 5,
  maxImageHeight: 5
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.1.2/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.1.2/css/fileinput.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-lg-6 col-12 mb-lg-0 mb-3 imagen-mascota">
  <input type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg" name="imagenes[]" id="imagenes" multiple>
</div>
```